# Java declare variable in ternary operation. Is it possible?

Tags: java, ternary-operator

Say we have some `city` with `String getZIP()` method.
I want to print value of ZIP or don't print anything if ZIP is null.

I can do it in one line of code with ternary operation:

```
System.out.print(city.getZIP() == null ? "" : city.getZIP())
```

The question is: can I do the same without calling `.getZIP()` twice?
Something like:

```
System.out.print(String zip = city.getZIP() == null ? "" : zip) //syntax error here
```

Comment: then the zip would only exist in that scope, meaning it's useless in the rest of your code

Comment: you could also just create the variable before the print call and check this variable?

Comment: @Sloth why would you want to do that

Comment: @BalajiKrishnan I was looking for a way to make it in one line of code without creating extra local variable outside ternary operation and without calling the method twice.

Comment: How would you benefit by that. Either you call the getter twice or end up with an additional local variable. I don't see any benefit

Comment: In this specific case it might be useless, but if the getter is more costly like a map lookup or something...

Comment: It would be useful in a return to make code shorter and more readable if you have one last condition that'll decide what is returned.
`return (int randomIsWhatIWant = random() == WhatIWant)?-1:randomIsWhatIWant;` 
WhatIWant would come from somewhere else within the function (random is an example if you didn't get it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can assign the value to an existing variable, but not create one inside the ternery condition.

Something like,

```
String zip; // Created elsewhere but not assigned to city.getZip().
System.out.print(((zip = city.getZIP()) == null) ? "" : zip)
```

But you can't declare a new variable inside.

Answer (score 4):

Define the variable in a separate line :

```
String zip = city.getZIP();
System.out.print(zip == null ? "" : zip);
```

Comment: I know about this way, but I'm asking if one line solution exists.

Comment: Read my question please. I'm not looking for solution of some problem.

Comment: @Sloth: Then what *are* you looking for?  If there isn't a problem, why are you trying to create one?

Comment: @David I'm looking for the way to make code short and rational.

Comment: @Sloth: The code in this answer does exactly that.  To the asked question of `"can I do the same without calling .getZIP() twice?"`, this is the answer.  It's not clear what else you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @David I'm trying to manage this case in one line of code without creating extra local variable and without calling a method twice.

Comment: @Sloth: If the `getZip()` operation is costly, cache the result internally to the `city` object so calling the method twice doesn't incur the same cost twice.  Otherwise, store the result in a variable external to the object.  (A refactoring pattern called Extract Variable: http://refactoring.com/catalog/extractVariable.html)  This quest to "store a result without having to store a result" seems unproductive.

Answer (score 2):

I have a completely different solution for you: **don't do that**.

Do not put methods on your classes that return **null** as "legit" result.

For example: zip code could / should be its own class. And then you simply declare some singleton instance of ZIP to represent "ZIP code is undefined". And then calling toString on "UnknownZip" ... just gives an empty string for example.

Using null as return value always opens up the chance for NullPointerExceptions.

So - don't do that.

Comment: Specifically, this is a refactoring pattern called Introduce Null Object: http://refactoring.com/catalog/introduceNullObject.html

Comment: Read the question please

Comment: I read your question; and I am simply suggesting you to forget about subtle syntax issues and instead focus on the much more important design problem behind your question.

Comment: you are not always 100% the producer of code, you could be a client, and in this case, I think Java misses something take a look on how horrible is this `String title = info.getTitle() == null ? "" : ("Title= " + info.getTitle());` while you cannot do otherwise.